# IBM SDK policy files

Tags: linux, java, encryption, redhat-enterprise-linux, coldfusion

We installed IBM websphere on a RHEL 6 server, and it came with its own version of java.

However, the encryption module on the box doesn't work, because it complains about :

```
 java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at com.cmsi.eValuate.Encryption.CryptoSafeNetImpl.decryptString(CryptoSafeNetImpl.java:286)
    at com.cmsi.eValuate.Encryption.EncryptionModuleMain.decryptString(EncryptionModuleMain.java:224)
    at
```

On searching the internet, they ask you to copy two policy files, US_policy.jar and export_policy.jar.

On using the policy.jar from an Oracle website, it causes Coldfusion admin to stop, and doesn't resolve the encryption problem.

On using the policy.jar from IBM website, it causes Coldfusion admin to stop, and doesn't resolve the encryption problem.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.security.component.doc.50%2Findex.html

We are using Java 6 on our box. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where the right policy files can be downloaded from?

Answer (score 0):

You need "Unlimited Jurisdiction File" - Java 6 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html

Java 7: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Install instructions should work from this site (first google result for `install jcepolicyfiles`: http://www.ngs.ac.uk/tools/jcepolicyfiles

Why? Because some ciphers (key lengths!) can't be exported to some countries.

Please check if you are not affected by USA Export Policy on Encryption: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_in_the_United_States

**EDIT:** Links above are for SUN/Oracle Java. OP is using IBM JVM and he needs this file:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/security/index.html

Comment: It caused ColdFusion admin to crash, and ColdFusion stopped working

Comment: What error message this time?

Comment: in CF server.log i see this 
"Warning","server.startup : 2","06/11/13","11:51:33",,"Datasource not found: origenate You must have JCE installed in your Java Runtime Evironment. The error was: javax.crypto.b (initialization failure)"